# WPF datagrid scrolling issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scroll

there is a search View ( app is a MVP - PRISM WPF ) which had some issue with scrolling. it took hell of a long time to scroll when you click the scroll bar buttons. Click and dragging the scroll bar was even worse!!

considering i like anomalies, i picked it and started looking into what was going wrong. I suspected many things, but evidently the issue with the datagrid scroll was due to "ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll=True" i removed it and the scrolling was a pleasant experience compared with earlier.

Now i was wondering why my developers had put that property as true, with in couple of mins i found Doing a Page down was scrolling more than a page with out the CanContentScroll property marked true!

Now i need the scrolling to be faster AND i also need page down and page up to scroll as expected! Can some one tell me What I am missing here?? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my datagrid : slow scrolling, and also randomly size changing scrollbar.
I did the following:

1. simplify the templates of the cells (no more nested borders and multiple colors, ToggleButtons instead of CheckBoxes)
2. in code use frozen colors.
   this helped speed things up but did not solve the issue.

Then i set the row / cells templates height and also the RowHeight property, and then it was ok : i had both smooth scrolling and normal scrollbar. So i guess that the DataGrid was unable to compute the size of what remained to be displayed that made both the scroll slow and the scrollbar having changing size.
(Yet the rows / cells were all having same actual height in their templates since they were defined with same controls but Height property was not set...)

Hope that can help.